# How to create a 2 second delay in my code?

Tags: java, minecraft

I need to create a delay during my loop so that the loop only changes the color of the bossbar every 2 seconds, but I can't use Thread.sleep because that pauses the entire server and eventually crashes it. How do I create a delay like this? Surely there's just a simple 1 line method I can call to do this, I mean with Python all I have to do is type 'sleep(2)'.

Comment: Do your operation in another thread where you can wait.

Comment: Your loop should NOT execute on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The EDT is responsible for responding to events and repainting the GUI (which it can't do if you have long running looping code). The looping code should execute on a separate Thread. You can use a `SwingWorker` for this. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples of using a SwingWorker.

Comment: AntoineB - I don't even know what a thread is much less how to create another one.

camickr - I have no idea what your talking about. When you say repainted, you just mean like retextured right? A resource pack can just do that for you. Also I dont think I have any control over the spigot thread thingy, I think the server can't not run on the main thread or whatever.

Comment: *I have no idea what your talking about.* - which is why I gave you a link to a tutorial to read. *I think the server can't not run on the main thread * - that is exactly what I suggested and I gave you the solution (which you can find by reading the tutorial).

Comment: You sent me a link that assumes I'm already familiar with concurrency and swing programming. Until today, I had never even heard of those!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bukkit try to call the scheduler to make the task run on a timer
this is a link for an in-depth explanation ->  [tutorial](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming)

here is some code for creating a delayed task

```
public void methodThatChangesBossbar() {
BukkitScheduler scheduler = getServer().getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                //decrease bossbar health here....
                //when your finished with this method just use 'return' to break the loop.

             }, [put delay before each time this method runs, 2000 = 2 seconds],  [offset before method first runs];
}
```

remember the last arguments are time expressed in milliseconds

Comment: I'm very new to spigot and I understand hardly any of whats on that page. It says "Plugins should first extend BukkitRunnable to define work that needs to be done. In other words, the definition of the run method is what you want executed in accordance to a schedule." What is BukkitRunnable, what's the run method, and why do I need a scheduler? I don't need a repeating timer, the for loop already covers that. I just need it to simply pause for 2 seconds. Surely you don't have to create a bunch of functions and variables to do that?

Comment: The for loops does not cover what you need done without messing with the actual server timings/threads  you need to create a whole new class/method for the timer, ill paste some of my code I used before in my answer, the bukkit runnable is just like the actuall runnable in java, if you know how to use one, you can use the other as well.

Comment: Ok but what is a runnable?

Comment: Where do I put that code? In my main class? If so on what line?

Comment: @Herobrine a runnable is a interface that if any class extends can be used as a thread,  whenever you want just create a new class, make it extend runnable, and when you make a new thread, put the class instance in the thread as a parameter like this : Thread aThreadThing = new Thread(classThatExtendedRunnable);  and you will see that everything in the run method in the class ran,  this sounds very confusing, but watch a few videos on it and it might be easier to understand

Comment: @Herobrine you put this code in any class you want, but when that method is called this code executes on the runnable task

Comment: I changed the code so that it is now a method that can be called

Comment: Also It is VERY important that you make sure to call 'return' when what you want is finished because if you dont there will be an infinite loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216301/discussion-between-riverman2010-and-herobrine).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println("Runnable: " + t);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(runnable2);
t.start();
```

Comment: Ok but where do I put that code, in the loop, in my main class, in my JoinListener class? I already said I can't use thread.sleep because that pauses the entire server. What is a Runnable variable? Also why do you need all that code just to create a 2 second delay?

Comment: @Herobrine you would want to put this within a method